# Is there a portable way to get the path of a resource in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

One of my unit tests is driven by test data, stored in `src/test/resources/testData.txt`. Since Maven will copy the contents of `src/test/resources` to `target/test-classes/` which is on the classpath, I can read that file conveniently from the classpath without caring about its absolute file name. So far, so good.

Now I'm in the process of witing some code that will update that file with data fetched from a remote system. That code will be run rarely, and not as part of the build. The updated file will be committed to the source repository. In order to append to the file, I need to know the path to the original file in `src/test/resources` (appending to the one in `target/test-classes/` will obviously not work).

How do I determine that path in a portable way? I'd rather not hard code `src/test/resources/`, because those directory names may actually change. Also, this would break if executed with a current working directory other than my project base directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be with `${project.basedir}/src/test/resources`. The test resource directory is unlikely to change, and it will safely resolve to the correct path regardless of your working directory. Trying to reference a test resource directory via a property is problematic because there can be, and often are, multiple test resources defined. How would you know which one to pick?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. `${project.basedir}/src/test/resources` would be fine, but how do I resolve the value of `${project.basedir}` from my code?

Comment: Typically, you'd have a properties file alongside your tests with a line like `myFile.path=${project.basedir}/src/test...`, and you'd [filter the properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) at build-time, getting the correct path plugged in by maven.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that's a very reasonable solution to my problem. However, it means maintaining a separate file containing build configuration in addition to the POM, which I'd like to avoid if possible. Inspired by your suggestion, I found a different solution which I personally prefer, and which I'll post as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution to this is to configure the surefire plugin to expose the `${project.basedir}` as an environment variable during test execution. Unit tests can then read that information from the environment if required. This keeps all configuration in the POM and will require no changes should that path ever change:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...
                <environmentVariables>
                    <maven.project.basedir>${project.basedir}</maven.project.basedir>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Other solutions could be implemented using resource filtering (as suggested by Ryan) or by configuring the surefire plugin to add `${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/` to the classpath.

Comment: Just for clarification, what I suggested in my answer can still keep all configuration in the POM. It just uses a fairly standard properties file to expose it to the tests. Whether your properties file has any actual values or is composed entirely of maven property placeholders is up to you. The main draw of the properties file is that it's fairly ubiquitous to Java frameworks as a method of configuration. Anything can read a properties file.